# Most stable way to convert a 32bit unsigned integer to big endian byte array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, type-conversion, unsigned-integer

What is the most stable and easiest way to convert a given (unsigned) integer into a four-byte-array with big endian and padding, if needed? Here's an example:

Input value:
`714`

Output: This byte array
`[ 0xca, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00 ];`

BTW: An npm module that is capable of doing this would be fine, too.

Background: I need this byte array as a prefix to an XML message that I send through a TCP socket in node.js. So I have a send buffer (a byte array) in which I put the prefix, then the rest of the buffer gets filled with the XML message's bytes.

Comment: Is your example not converting to big endian by `0x2ca` to `ca 02 00 00`..?

Comment: You're right, of course... fixed it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function should give you a string in the big endian format.

```js
function toBigEndian(n){
  return n.toString(16)
          .match(/[\da-f]/g)
          .reduceRight((r,c,i,a) => (a.length-i)%2 ? r.concat(c) : (r[r.length-1] = c + r[r.length-1],r),[])
          .map(s => s.length === 1 ? 0+s : s)
          .reduce((p,c,i,a) => i < a.length-1 ? p + " " + c : p + " " + c + " 00".repeat(~~((4-a.length))));
}

console.log(toBigEndian(714));
console.log(toBigEndian(20171453));
```

To be honest i didn't like the initial code of mine. Then, as per your comment, i have come up with another, much simpler solution. First i use a tool to convert from decimal to hex in the reverse order required. It's called `dec2hex`. Pretty simple.

```js
function dec2hex (n){
  return n ? [n%256].concat(dec2hex(~~(n/256))) : [];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(dec2hex(255)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(dec2hex(256)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(dec2hex(714)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(dec2hex(65535)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(dec2hex(65536)));
```

So by utilizing the above `dec2hex` tool we can much simply achieve our job.

```js
function dec2hex (n){
  return n ? [n%256].concat(dec2hex(~~(n/256))) : [];
}

function toBigEndian(n){
  var hexar = dec2hex(n);
  return hexar.map(h => (h < 16 ? "0x0" : "0x") + h.toString(16))
              .concat(Array(4-hexar.length).fill("0x00"));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(toBigEndian(714)));
```

You can include the hex in decimal numbers to hex in hex numbers (255 -> 0xff) convertion in the `dec2hex` function as well but i have thought one might be interested in decimal number representation of each byte so a left it for a later stage..

Comment: Thanks, Redu, this is some serious magic you have there! ;) I'll try do adapt your solution so that it returns a byte array. I think I didn't formulate it clearly enough in my example, I need an array of bytes such as var *myArray = [ 0xca, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00 ];*

Comment: OK I am a little confused... May i assume that you want to fill in an array with corresponding byte values..? I have made an addition to my answer please check to see if i am getting close.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve. It works now, thanks again!